# rhc command for openshift Mysql ip

Tags: php, mysql, openshift, openshift-client-tools

i need Mysql IP for custom wordpress installation as it not support "localhost" mysql host address.In rhc window client i use port forward command rhc port-forward -a appname but it show openshift IP address of HAPROXY and httpd not for Mysql.how to find openshift MYSQL IP.link for port-forward rhc command result iamge

[image: Example Command Line screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You can print the MySQL `<ip>:<port>` using the following command:

```
rhc ssh <app> 'echo $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'
```

However, it's recommended to use OpenShift's environment variables instead of hard-coded numbers, as they are generic and thus you don't need change anything while migrating the app from gear to gear:

```
/* Environment variables exposed by MySQL database cartridge */
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST')); // 127.0.250.1
define('DB_PORT', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT')); // 3306
define('DB_USER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME')); // admin
define('DB_PASS', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD')); // 8ddTnst22X3Y
define('DB_NAME', getenv('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME')); // myapp
define('DB_SOCKET', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_SOCKET')); // $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DIR/socket/mysql.sock
define('DB_STRING', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL')); // mysql://admin:8ddTnst22X3Y@127.0.250.1:3306/
```

Comment: vojtech vitek, i use rhc ssh <app> 'echo $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT' command too.but it give me same result 52eee....-upme.rhcloud.com:37501. is there is kind of order exist in which IP is assign to cartidge ?.if yes,then IP of MYSQL will be find as IP address of HAPROXY and httpd is known

Answer (score 1):

You can ssh into your app and run  `env | grep MYSQL`

Comment: how i ssh into app i already upload public key to openshift account

Comment: From the directory of your application run `rhc ssh -a <appname>`

Comment: after ssh into app how i type env | grep MYSQL my keyboard have no button like | morever paste function not work in cmd after ssh into app

Comment: after typing mysql command for ssh into app. It Opens an interactive MySQL shell. what command will be use to find mysql openshift IP?

Comment: after env|grep MYSQL command result still not show IP address:( http://imgur.com/pecVtIk

Comment: You should checkout https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example/blob/master/php/wp-config.php for an example of how wordpress is configured to work on Openshift

Comment: `rhc ssh -a <appname`> gives me "No system SSH available. Please use the --ssh option to specify the path to your SSH executable, or install SSH.", but I can deploy my app with SSH.

Answer (score 0):

SSH into your app using command `rhc ssh <app>` after ssh into your app, type in `env | grep MYSQL` then find `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST` and copy the value it has something like this `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST = 56********************43-<domain>.rhcloud.com` you need the second part, which is `56********************43-<domain>.rhcloud.com` then while you are still inside the shell (ssh) of your app, ping the address you just got, `ping 56********************43-<domain>.rhcloud.com` . the resulting IP is the MYSQL server IP. I usually use the port in `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL` attached to the ip.

This may (not sure) differ in different apps.

You can extract the value of `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL` from the `env | grep MYSQL` command I described above.

The value is something similar to this `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL=mysql://<MySQLusername>:<MySQLpassword>@56********************43-<domain>.rhcloud.com:61836`

You could extract all the required info from here too.

Good luck on using it!